# Razer Laptop Power MOSFET replacement

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics

I have a failed power mosfet on my board which is **PSMN3R0-30**

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN3R0-30YL.pdf

It has low Rds (on) = 3 mΩ

It is common for these to fail in these laptops (poor design) and would like to know if I can replace it with a more suitable mosfet. I have been looking at many datasheets for other mosfets (**30v, 100A**) but I just can't figure out what one would work in its place. Maybe these?

https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1579/0900766b815790d7.pdf

https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1560/0900766b81560cf4.pdf

I can buy the PSMN3R0-30 but not from the UK so shipping is expensive.

Thank you

Comment: No one here will tell you to use any other model MOSFET than the one that is originally used. Why is that? That's because we didn't design the circuit using this MOSFET so we don't know what the consequence will be of using a different MOSFET. *if I can replace it with a more suitable mosfet* So you know better than the **designers of the circuit** which MOSFET is "better". Hmm, maybe you should apply for a job at Razer!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I understand what you're saying. It is a well documented problem that the mosfets Razer used were very liable to fail. But I guess buying the same one will keep it going for a few more years

Comment: If you *did* want to try some light redesign on the circuit to make the FET last longer, you'd first need to diagnose the problem and then figure out how the current FET is lacking.  It could be that the problem isn't the FET at all, but some surrounding circuitry, in which case you'd need to redesign *that*.  All in all, for one laptop, if it takes a couple of years to fail you're probably better of just replacing the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search reveals that they fail because they overheat. The Rds is very low, so that is unlikely to be the problem (assuming that it is fully turned on). It could be that the Vgs is too low and it isn't fully turning on. Or, it is used in a PWM circuit and it is switching too slowly. You would need to scope a working circuit to diagnose the marginal design issue.

I would not recommend attempting to substitute a different part without a diagnosis, you could make it worse.

You might consider attempting to heatsink it better, but space is tight in laptops and it is unlikely to have enough space. You could also block airflow and make it worse.